# Looking for a method for boxes to be printed the one next to another

Tags: java

I have a university project to create a maze game that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Sug.png)

The problem is that they cant appear the one next to another if I make them like this because i cant return to the previous line to print the new box next to it.

```
String array1= new String[3];
for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
   array1[i]=" "+"_____"+"\n"+"|     |"+"\n"+"|_____|";
}
for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
   System.out.print(array1[i]);
}
```

When i print this it will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv5dd.jpg). So is there a method to make the boxes to be printed the one next to another?

Answer (score 1):

> i cant return to the previous line to print the new box next to it

One possibility might be to construct the maze image in memory, where you have random access to any part of it. Once you are done with it, you could print it out line by line.